# Create new projet PhoneGap Starter with C# Express Edition

Tags: cordova, windows-phone

I'm under Microsoft Windows 7 Pro 64 bytes.

I have installed **Microsoft Visual C# Express Edition**, **Microsoft Windows Phone SDK 7.1** and downloaded the  phonegab 1.3.

I have copied in directory C:\Users\francis\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Templates\ProjectTemplates the 2 templates zip **PhoneGapCustom.zip and PhoneGapStarter.zip.**

So when i create a new project PhoneGapStarter in Microsoft Visual C# Express Edition, i have this message : ***impossible to open the project  C:\Users\john\AppData\Local\Temp\nwlc5jb5.yze\PhoneGapStarter.csproj'. project type is not supported by this installation.***

Have you an idea?